# How was this person able to comment?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

Okay, so I'm filing this under a bug report because I don't see how this person should have been able to comment. The user [Claudio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/21825/claudio) (who is unregistered, and currently has 1 reputation) left [a comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55964/are-spectre-or-veteran-packs-more-cost-effective/55981#comment82077_55981) on [my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55981/15643) to a question he did not ask. I was under the impression that users under 50 rep could only comment on either their own answers or the question/answers to a question they asked. So how was this person able to leave a comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mods can convert answers to comments.

That is what Agent86 has done in this case, because what Claudio originally posted shouldn't have been posted as an answer in the first place.

Comment: Got it. Yeah, that makes sense and I hadn't considered that. Thanks